# What is $a'\cdot a'$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra, boolean-ring

Since, $a+a'=1$ and $a.a'=0$ (Boolean Algebra complement laws), where $a$ is a variable and $a'$ is its complement. Can you please explain what $a'.a'=$ would be?

Also, please prove your result as well. I'm just confused what $a'.a'$ can be?

Comment: DonÄt you also have somethin like idempotency laws?

Answer (score 1):

The multiplication operation is idempotent:

$$a\cdot a = a$$

Proof: by enumerating all possible values of $a$ and checking.

Comment: Won't the result differ for compliments. So you mean, a'.a'= a' ?

Comment: Yes. Idempotency states that for all a, $a\cdot a = a$. In particular, for all b, supposing $a = b'$, we have $b' \cdot b' = b'$.

Comment: @Wayne If you really want to convince yourself, prove $a' \cdot a' = a'$ by by enumerating all possible values of $a$ and $a'$ and  then checking.